# How to see the dataset of bigquery in google cloud which is shared by someone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

How can we see the datasets in Bigquery, which is shared by someone to our email

Comment: What do you mean with "to our email"? Is the user account email?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested of public BigQuery datasets, you can find them in GCP Marketplace catalog. Please check this link for public dataset location and accessing public datasets in BigQuery [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/#sharing_a_dataset_with_the_public).

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the project in which the dataset exists. This information should be provided if you have multiple projects.Then, to the bottom left of your bigquery console, you can see all the datasets associated to the project , you can type initials of the dataset and can simply search.
To access projects and dataset related information, you have to have proper set of permissions. For further info on permissions, please read the google documentation: 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/listing-datasets